# focus nth item on Jquery Mobile listview

Tags: jquery, listview, jquery-mobile

I have around 100 items in a jQuery Mobile listivew. Is it possible to focus on Nth element in a listview that is generated dynamically??

I know is possible in Android and iPhone but not sure how it is done in jQuery Mobile.

Thanks for your time in advance.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/ is this what you mean?

Comment: I need to scroll to the nth element. not to select the nth element's dom. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

jQuery Mobile does support  `scrollTop` so you could do something like this:

```
$(document).scrollTop($(".ui-listview:eq(1) li:eq(21)").position().top);
```

Or update your selectors to match the `li` you would like to scroll to.

The code above works on the jqm list view example page. Try it!  Go here: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/lists/lists-ul.html and enter the code above in your console. It should scroll down to the last item.

**UPDATE**

After looking up something else in the jqm documentation, I came across this:

//scroll to Y 300px
$.mobile.silentScroll(300);

Found here: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-scripting.html, under "Scrolling to a position within a page". The trick with this is that it was designed to help preserve page position and back button behavior.

Hope this helps!